# struct or enums for localization keys and constants in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, static

i have been using enums and structs for storing global variables using static keyword. i also use the same technique for localization keys. e.g. i make a file with enum and define variables with static let so that i can access it easily. example

```
    enum LocalizationKeys {
        static let firstKey = "testKey" <-- this is the key which is in localization file
    }
```

for constants i use this too. i was thinking that i have like 5000 static variables, will that affect memory management in anyway ?

if this is not the good way, can someone please guide and show the right way.

Comment: what if you use English value as a key for a language like en "Done" = "Done";  for es "Done" = "es word for done"

Comment: For regular constants, static properties on enums are perfectly fine. However, for localisation keys specifically, I'd suggest using enum cases, since your localisation keys have to be coming from a known, finite set of values declared in your localisations file. Also, there are frameworks which generate said enum for you automatically, such as [R.swift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift).